# When I write a update log in a document, do I need to add a period after a sentence if it's followed by a dash sign and a Date?

Tags: punctuation

I have a document, it can be any topic. And after a while, I have updated the document and I want to let my readers know which part is changed.

So I added something like:

Added more description text for the paragraph that describes the bird. - Jul 7, 2023

Or

Fixed some typos in the last paragraph. - Jul 7, 2023

There are two ways:

- Fixed some typos in the last paragraph. - Jul 7, 2023
- Fixed some typos in the last paragraph - Jul 7, 2023

With the period or without it.

Which one should I choose to make the document looks professional?

Thanks

Comment: It's a matter of style, or preference, since you're *not* writing full sentences, which *should* have end punctuation. If you're working with others, follow the approved style if an organization, or one you agree upon. [BTW, styles change. For example, I've noticed bibliographical citations change from *Title Case* to only *Capitalizing first word*.]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May I ask why "Fixed some typos in the last paragraph." is not a full sentence?

Comment: In English, sometimes, the *subject* of a sentences is "understood", e.g., *Go!* is the shortest full sentence. One might say the subject "I" is understood in your example, but in *formal* English usage, that likely would be unacceptable. A log is *not* formal English, though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about learning English; the same issue would likely arise in many other languages, too. The folks at Writing SE might be able to give advice about writing style for revision logs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to. You are not writing in full sentences, but making a list.

If I were to use full stops, I'd add them after the date, since the date is part of the structure that could be expanded to a sentence if you were writing in paragraphs.

> Fixed errors - 7/6/23.

Means  "I fixed errors on the seventh of June 2023."  And the full stop goes after the date.  But it is just a matter of personal preference.